# How to turn off shuffle of List

Tags: android, shuffle

I created `my_list` data:

```
for (int i=0; i<14; i++)
   my_list[i] = new Person("number " i);
}
```

I used method shuffle to randomly `my_list`:

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(my_list));
```

So, I want turn off shuffle of `my_list`!

Comment: Stop calling `Collections.shuffle`? I'm not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: How to stop it?

Comment: Please post your full code.  I don't see an actual question here.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Still I don't follow...why can't you just deleted the line `Collections.shuffle` to stop the shuffling?

Comment: I used a button to turn on and off my_list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct if you want to shuffle your my_list data

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(my_list));
```

But if you don't want to shuffle it then you don't need to put the Collections.shuffle

I will consider my_list as a string array..

To get `String[]` then use

```
my_list
```

To get `List<String`> from my_list array

```
 List<String> tempList = Arrays.asList(my_list);
```

I dont know if this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you, Great idea ^^

Comment: No problem. I am glad I was able to help you. ^^